# Не сохраняется красная строка в админке Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

Я создаю сайт-библиотеку, где имеется в том числе и тексты произведений. Сайт пишется на python/django

Проблема заключается в том, что при сохранении в админке пустые строки (между другими строками) и красные строки удаляются и получается текст без них. Возможно ли как-то их сохранить? Или может подскажете другой способ?

Про linebreaks и pre-wrap знаю, здесь проблемка именно в админке

Comment: Используемое поле -- textfield

Comment: попробуйте  wysiwyg редактор (хз как правильно пишется). тогда каждый обзац будет обернут тегом  `p`, что сделает то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @ZaArs, спасибо большое, добавил себе ckeditor, всё работает) Не знал раньше про эту штук